# DataSourcePublicMetrics Not Available in Spring boot 2.1.3

Tags: spring-boot, sharding, hikaricp

We are using a sharded database where we want to have metrics about each shard. We were using Spring Boot 1.5.9 and recently we upgraded to Spring Boot 2.1.3. For the metrics in the sharded database we were extending org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.DataSourcePublicMetrics, but it seems this is gone now with the new Spring Boot version.
That class allowed the method ``public Collection> metrics()` to be added whhich adds custom metrics.

How can we achieve this same behavior with the new version?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: This class changed packages to `org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.DataSourcePublicMetrics`

Comment: For some reason i don't see it in Spring Boot 2.1.3.